# Give a counter-example to show translation is not continuous on $L^p$ when $p = \infty$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lp-spaces

A function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{C}$ is said to be $L^p$-continuous if $\tau_h(f)\to f$ in $L^p(\mathbb{R}^n;\mathbb{C})$ as $h\to 0$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, where $\tau_h(f)(x)=f(x-h)$ is the translation of $f$ by $h$. If $1\leq p< \infty$ every $f\in L^p(\mathbb{R}^n;\mathbb{C})$ is $L^p$-continuous. Give a counter-example to show this result is not true when $p=\infty$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Where is the question

Comment: I upvoted because of the first question. Welcome to MSE

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/69687/169085

Answer (score 1):

$\|I_{(a,b)}(x)-I_{(a,b)}(x-h))\|_{\infty} =1$ whenever $h  \neq 0$.

Comment: What is $I_{(a,b)}$?

Comment: It is the function which has the value $1$ on the interval $(a,b)$ and $0$ outside the interval.

Answer (score 0):

For instance, consider any function $f\in L^\infty(\Bbb R^n)$ which is continuous but not uniformly continuous (exercise for you is to see where continuity comes into play).

Comment: You  have to consider a bounded continuous function which is not uniformly continuous.

Comment: Well, ok, bounded is kind of demanded by the hypothesis.