# Approximate identities that are not $L_1$

Tags: probability, functional-analysis

Suppose I have a random variable $X$ with a density on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and a family of random variables $Y_\delta$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the property that $\|Y_\delta\|_2 \leq \delta$ with probability $1$. Is it true that $X + Y_\delta$ (adding independent copies) tends to $X$ in total variation distance as $\delta \to 0$? If the $Y_\delta$'s had a densities this is well known, but I can't find a reference in case $Y_\delta$ does not have a density. It still feels true to me, however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I only consider the case $X+\delta Y$, where $X$ and $Y$ are independent, and $\delta>0$.

Suppose $\nu$ any Borel probability measure on $\mathbb{R}^d$, and let $f\in L^+_1(\lambda_d)$ (where $\lambda_d$ is Lebesgue's measure on $\mathbb{R}^d$) be such that $\int f=1$. Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables with laws $\mu:=d\lambda_d$ and $\nu$, respectively. Then $X+ \delta Y$ has law with density
$$h_\delta(x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}f(x-\delta y)\nu(dy)$$
By Fubini's theorem
$$\begin{align}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}|h_\delta(x)-f(x)|\,dx&=\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\Big|\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}f(x-\delta y)-f(x)\,\nu(dy)\Big|\,dx\\
&\leq\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\Big(\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}|f(x-\delta y)-f(x)|\,dx\Big)\,\nu(dy)
\end{align}$$
Since $\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}|f(x-\delta y)-f(x)|\,dx\leq 2\|f\|_1=2$ and $\lim_{\delta\rightarrow0}\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}|f(x-\delta y)-f(x)|\,dx=0$, dominated convergence yields
$$\|h_\delta - f\|_{L_1(\lambda_d)}\xrightarrow{\delta\rightarrow0}0.$$

Comment: How do you know that $\int_{\mathbb R^d}\vert f(x-\delta y)-f(x)\vert\,dx\underset{\delta\to0}{\longrightarrow}0$?

Comment: The translation operator is continuous in $L_p(\lambda_d)$ for any $p\geq1$. This can be seen in many textbooks in real analysis. There are a few postings in MSE that discuss this too, for example [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/69687/121671)

Comment: Alright, thanks

Comment: Great answer, thanks! Should $\mu$ be $f$ (or whatever the appropriate notation is for the measure with density $f$ w.r.t. Lebesgue)? And do you happen to know if this fact appears in any textbook?

Comment: With regards to $\mu$, yes, I just made an edit. I forgot to write $\mu=fd\lambda_d$, where $\lambda_d$ is Lebesgue's measure. As for references, almost any textbook an real analysis (Follland's, Rudin's, Widden-Sygmund's) will dedicate some part to the continuity of the translation operator, Fubini's theorem, as well as the Radon-Nikodym theorem. There is also a concept, which I did not comment about, known as good kernels and approximations to identity. I think one can generalize the, carefully with kernels that are singular with respect Lebesgue measure.